# In (python3) psycopg2 return results as string rather than dict

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

In psycopg2, is there a way for the cursor to return results as a string rather than a JSON (or string) format rather than as a dictionary object?

**Example**

```
# connect to database 
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, user=usr, password=passwd, dbname=dbn) 
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
# CREATE table and INSERT 
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t1(c char, i int);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO t1(c, i) VALUES ('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)"); 
# Execute query 
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;") 
output1 = cur.fetchall() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t1;")
output2 = cur.fetchall()
```

**Expect** - List of objects formatted as JSON or strings

```
output1 - ['{"count": 3}']
output2 - ['{"c": "a", "i": 1}', '{"c": "b", "i": 2}', '{"c": "c", "i": 3}']
```

**Actual** - List of dictionary objects

```
output1 - [{'count': 3}]
output2 - [{'c': 'a', 'i': 1}, {'c': 'b', 'i': 2}, {'c': 'c', 'i': 3}]
```

I'm currently using the JSON module to convert each object into a JSON, but am wondering if there is a simpler way (ie within psycopg2).

Comment: `output1 = json.dumps(cur.fetchall())` is not simple enough?

Comment: @klin, I gave a simple example but the real situation contains datetime.datetime objects, thus if I use your method I get an error. Meaning that in order to use the json function, I have to update the list and then convert the JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current way of rendering your view in your application is correct, and you should continue doing so.

In principle, there is a way to render your view as JSON inside PostgreSQL, but to do so would make no sense whatsoever, since rendering your views is the furthest you can get from what the role of a database would be in your architecture.

Comment: And by the way @OShadmon, I want to commend you for taking architectural advice. The ability to see one's own mental constructs from different and conflicting points of view is what separates men from boys and women from girls.